# Is there any telephony framework in linux?

Tags: linux, telephony

I have a [USB 3g modem](http://cgi.ebay.in/Huawei-3G-USB-Modem-E173-7-2Mbps-HSDPA-5-76Mbps-HSUPA-/280717541890?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item415c11c202#ht_988wt_1141), On windows it comes with software with which, I can use it for calling, sending and receiving SMS. Now, I want to write similar open source application in linux ( I also want to provide DTMF detection functionality ).

In windows, we can achieve this through TAPI, what are the similar technologies/frameworks in linux? Is there any similar opensource application ( I want to use as a reference )?

Comment: h.323 protocol if your device supports it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is is called [ofono](http://ofono.org/) - project started by Intel/Nokia for Maemo/Moblin. From wikipedia:

> oFono is a free, open source project for mobile telephony (GSM/UMTS)
>   applications. It uses high-level D-Bus API for use by telephony
>   applications. It uses 3GPP standard. It is free software released
>   under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2.

And Asterisk and Freeswitch are [PBX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_PBX) software and probably are not what you are looking for.

Comment: Many Thanks for pointing out at ofono. I was not aware of it, I was knowing Asterisk ( But found it too big and not flexible enough to work with simple modems. ) +1

Answer (score 2):

[Freeswitch](http://www.freeswitch.org/)

I'm not sure about a USB modem, but for VOIP telephony, Freeswitch is excellent.  It uses a generic socket API to make it extensible via any number of languages.  It can handle inbound and outbound calls, text-to-speech, voice recognition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My Vodafone Merlin card was recognized as a ttySx ant it was possible to interact by simple AT-commands like with old analog modems. There were also extra commands for reasing the sim card address book, sms and I believe also for sending sms.

Comment: The Vodafone Merlin is an 3G cardbus card which I had placed in an PCI-cardbus adapter. This was a few years ago, so I'm sorry I cannot provide details.

Answer (score 1):

We use sms tools: http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/

> The SMS Server Tools 3 is a SMS Gateway software which can send and receive short messages through GSM modems and mobile phones.
>
> You can send short messages by simply storing text files into a special spool directory. The program monitors this directory and sends new files automatically. It also stores received short messages into another directory as text files. Binary messages (including Unicode text) are also supported, for example ring tone messages. It's also possible to send a WAP Push message to the WAP / MMS capable mobile phone.
>
> The program can be run as a SMS daemon which can be started automatically when the operating system starts. High availability can be ensured by using multiple GSM devices (currently up to 64, this limit is easily changeable).
>
> The program can run other external programs or scripts after events like reception of a new message, successful sending and also when the program detects a problem. These programs can inspect the related text files and perform automatic actions, for example storing information into a database (for example MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server), sending an automatic reply, forwarding messages via eMail (SMS to eMail gateway), ... and whatever you like."

Comment: Ok, this is for SMS, what about callng?

Comment: Sorry, I got stuck on the SMS part of your question and missed the voice.  We use Asterisk and VOIP for that.  I don't know if that can use your modem or not.

Comment: Johan, Can you tell me why it is not possible to use USB modem with Asterisk?

Comment: Many people I asked replied me that, It is not possible to have USB modem work with Asterisk, I really want to know the reason.

Comment: One more thing is, in linux for voice call, is there only Asterisk framework not any thing else?

Comment: There are user friendly Asterisks such as trixbox.  I don't know of anything else though.  Twillo might be useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk would be the usual suspect for what you want - http://www.asterisk.org/